# Convert unix time from variable to normal time in AIX

Tags: date, aix

-d doesn't work(date: Not a recognized flag: d):

```
date -d @1141421607
```

and awk's

```
awk -vNEXTEXECDATUM="$NEXTEXECDATUM" 'BEGIN { print strftime("%c", NEXTEXECDATUM); exit }'
```

doesn't work: "awk: 0602-553 Function strftime is not defined."

**My question**: how can I convert unix time from variable to normal time in AIX?

Comment: Probably the easiest way: install GNU coreutils and just use the GNU date then ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AIX comes with Perl, so use that for your requirement.

```
perl -le 'print scalar localtime(shift)' 1141421607
Fri Mar  3 16:33:27 2006
```