# script with date work on Linux but not on AIX

Tags: linux, shell-script, date, ksh, aix

I wrote a script to that works fine on Linux but fails on AIX 7.2.
My script uses the command `date` with -d.
The purpose of this script is to get the last day that is not a Saturday, Sunday or a holiday. To validate if a day is a holiday I perform a query passing a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

The script is this:

```
D_MINUS_ONE=

GetLastDay()
{
        current_day=""
        day_of_week=$(date -d "$1 -1 days" +'%w')
        if [ $day_of_week -eq 0 ]
        then
                current_day=$(date -d "$1 -3 days")
        else
                current_day=$(date -d "$1 -1 days")
        fi
        db2 -x "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOLIDAY WHERE DT_HOLIDAY='$(date -d "$current_day" +'%Y-%m-%d')'" | read lines
        if [ lines -gt 0 ]
        then
                GetLastDay $(date -d "$current_day" +'%Y-%m-%d')
        fi
        D_MINUS_ONE=$(date -d "$current_day" +'%Y-%m-%d')
}

GetLastDay $1

echo $D_MINUS_ONE
```

Comment: AIX's date doesn't "do" -d; I'll suggest https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119404/117549 as a possible duplicate, although an Answerer here could work perl into a specific answer for you (or you could!)  Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97913/117549

Comment: by "last day" do you mean "last _working_ day"? I see you subtracting 3 days if "yesterday" lands on a Sunday.

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller, by last day I mean only working days that aren't holidays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-d` is a GNU `date` extension (`busybox` and `ast-open` `date` also have one though work differently).

AIX comes with `ksh93` though, so no need for GNU `date` to get the previous working day:

```
day=2016-01-01
previous_working_day=$(D=$day ksh93 -c '
  printf "%(%F)T" "$D, $(($(printf "%(%w)T" "$D") == 1 ? 3 : 1)) day ago"')
```

Comment: Stéphane, thank you. That's what I need to make it works on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

```
D_MINUS_ONE=

GetLastDay()
{
        last_day=$(D=$1 ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%F)T" "$D, $(($(printf "%(%w)T" "$D") == 1 ? 3 : 1)) day ago"')
        db2 -x "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOLIDAY WHERE DT_HOLIDAY='$last_day'" | read lines
        if [ lines -gt 0 ]
        then
                GetLastDay $last_day
        fi
        D_MINUS_ONE=$last_day
}

GetLastDay $1

echo $D_MINUS_ONE
```